# CSS - rating stars

Tags: css, input, radio-button

I am trying to create a rating "system" in CSS without using labels and I managed to kind of fake it for now. However, I have a problem where the style doesn't get applied on `hover`.

[image: Hover effects]

So, when I hover over a non checked element, its color should become purple, but what happens is that the purple color gets applied only to the siblings after it and not the one that is hovered (it should apply to both the hovered and the ones after). However, when I hover over the checked element, the styles get applied correctly (hover color gets applied to the checked element and all elements after that one).

My CSS:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: row;
}

input {
  visibility:hidden;
}

input:before {
  display: flex;
  content: '★';
  font-size: 50px;
  visibility: visible;
}

input:checked,
input:checked ~ input:before {
  color: green;
}

input:hover,
input:hover ~ input:before {
  color: purple;
}
```

Am I missing something specific here because I can't figure it out.

Comment: should be `input:hover:before` since the color need to go to the pseudo element (PS: share your html code)

Comment: Is this what you wanted to achieve? https://codepen.io/TheDeadviper/pen/wbQzpZ